# Rails: Anchor Tag to jump to location on same page without sending a new request and having to re-render the page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is how I thought you do this.  For the place you want to jump to, you simply specify an id:

```
<h1 id="top_of_blogs_list">TOP OF WEBPAGE</h1>
```

And then if you want to jump there from somewhere on a webpage via a link, you simply specify an anchor tag for that link:

```
  <%= link_to "Back to Top", blogs_path(anchor: "top_of_blogs_list")%>
```

The issue is that this is sending a brand new request to the server and re-rendering the entire page.  I do not want to send a new request to the server. I want to keep the current page as it is currently rendered, and simply jump up to where that id of `"top_of_blogs_list"` is specified.

Perhaps this must be done using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the blogs_path.  This should suffice:

```
<%= link_to "Back to Top", '#top_of_blogs_list' %>
```